# Multiply each number in array in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I need to write a program that multiply each number in array by himself..

For example, if my array is: [1,2,3,4]

The output of that will be: [1,4,9,16]

The multiply operation must work like this: instead of doing `3x3` it must be '3+3+3', and before every sum operation I must load the number from the array and after every sum operation I must store it.

I'm new to Assembly, so this is what I've got so far and I can't think of a program that work fine..

```
    .data
arr:    .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

    .text
main:
    la $a0, arr
    li $a1, 10
    j loop

loop:
    beq $a1, 0, end
    lw $t0, ($a0)
    add $t1, $0, $t0
    addi $t2, $0, 0
    addi, $a1, $a1, -1
    j mltp

mltp:
    beq $t1, 0, loop
    lw $t3, ($a0)
    add $t2, $t2, $t3
    sw $t2, ($a0)
    addi $t1, $t1, -1
    j mltp

end:
```

It's probably all wrong, please help me understand how to do it correctly and more efficient :)

Comment: A [mcve] has to explain what actually happens when you run it, if that's different from the desired result.  Preferably also, use the debugger to single-step a few examples and find out why exactly it doesn't work.  Or if you already know that, then write an algorithm in C or pseudocode.

Comment: You don't need to load / store inside the mult loop.  But you do need a counter separate from the multiplier.